# Unable to control memory utilization on server increasing with ruby process

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memory-management

I have a Rails 3.2 application running on production server. The server has 8 GB of RAM and every other process works fine. But, there is a ruby process which keeps the memory utilization on the higher side. I have to manually login to the server console and type the TOP command and kill the process using the PID.

But, I am unable to figure out how to check which ruby process is taking so much of memory and also how to control it permanently.

Please suggest me a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be so many things. Finding memory leaks is tough. What kind of application server are you using? If you're using Unicorn consider checking out Puma. It's actually really easy to switch over. We saw big gains in our app when we switched to Puma.

Also look through your app for n+1 queries. Optimizing some queries here and there would help tremendously.

Another thing you could consider trying is moving some longer running tasks to a background job with something like sidekiq.

Lots of performance monitoring services out there, like New Relic, that you could check out as well. Without more info it's a tough question to answer.